# Python processes and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, linux, indexing

I am running several thousand python processes on multiple servers which go off, lookup a website, do some analysis and then write the results to a central MySQL database.

It all works fine for about 8 hours and then my scripts start to wait for a MySQL connection.
On checking top it's clear that the MySQL daemon is overloaded as it is using up to 90% of most of the CPUs.

When I stop all my scripts, MySQL continues to use resources for some time afterwards.
I assume it is still updating the indexes? - If so, is there anyway of determining which indexes it is working on, or if not what it is actually doing?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: "several thousand" are they one-off processes (spawn-task-die) or long-running processes?

Comment: They are long running processes, i.e. get some data and process it, get some more data and processes it, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the slow query log: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html

Also, take a look at the output of SHOW PROCESSLIST; on the mysql shell, it should give you some more information.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of tweaks that can be done to improve the performance of MySQL. Given your workload, you would probably benefit a lot from mysql 5.5 and higher, which improved performance on multiprocessor machines. Is the machine in question hitting VM? if it is paging out, then the performance of mysql will be horrible.

My suggestions:

- check version of mysql. If possible, get the latest 5.5 version.
- Look at the config files for mysql called my.cnf. Make sure that it makes sense on your machine. There are example config files for small, medium, large, etc machines to run MySQL. I think the default setup is for a machine with < 1 Gig of ram.
- As the other answer suggests, turn on slow query logging.